# track history of installed python packages

Tags: virtualenv, pip

The production code runs in a virtualenv.

The packages and the version numbers should be dumped regularly, to see if there was a version change.

Use case: the application does not behave like it should, and you need to find the source of the problem. It should be easy to see if there were changes (for example new packages).

I know `pip --freeze` and I know how to write a cronjob .... but somehow I think there could be a better solution.

Comment: Since the app has its own venv already, wouldn't it be easier to just create a ``requirements.txt`` and only install packages by changing it?

Comment: @Bogdan packages should not be installed by hand (on the production virtualenv). But it is possible. That's why I am paranoid and want to have the history of installed packages.

Comment: In that case wouldn't you want to make a snapshot of the running code from time to time as well? If some mysterious villain runs ``pip update`` at night, he can change the code just as easily.

Comment: `pip` and `virtualenv` don't update your packages automattically.